# Linearly independent natural logarithms

Tags: linear-algebra

Find every positive integers $n$ such that the set $\mathcal{S}=\{ln(x), ln(2x), \cdots, ln(nx)\}$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$.

I though the follows:

For example, if $n=1$, follows that $a_1.ln(x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$ implies that $a_1=0$. Then, for $n=1$ the set $\mathcal{S}$ is linearly independent. But, in general, if $a_1.ln(x)+a_2.ln(2x)+\cdots+a_n.ln(nx)=0$, we can write $(a_1+\cdots+a_n).ln(x)=-(a_2.ln(2)+ \cdots +a_n.ln(n))$
but fot this last equality can occur for $a_1, \cdots, a_n$ non zero, because the  logarithmic function is onto over $\mathbb{R}$. Then, for $n>1$ the set $\mathcal{S}$ is linearly dependent over $\mathbb{R}$.

My solution is correct? Thanks.

Comment: What is $x$ here? Is it fixed? That is, is the set $\mathcal{S}$ set of numbers or set of functions?

Answer (score 1):

Take $n>1$.

Suppose $\sum_k \alpha_k \ln (k x) = \sum_k \alpha_k \ln k + \ln x^{\sum_k \alpha_k} = 0 $ for all $x>0$. Then $\sum_k \alpha_k = 0$ and $\sum_k \alpha_k \ln k = 0$

Hence we look for a non zero solution to the linear system $\sum_k \alpha_k = 0$ and $\sum_k \alpha_k \ln k = 0$.

For $n =2$ the system is non singular, hence $x \mapsto \ln x, x \mapsto \ln (2x)$ are linearly independent.

For $n>2$, there are non zero solutions to the system (a $2 \times n$ matrix),
hence the collection  $x \mapsto \ln x, \cdots,  x \mapsto \ln (nx)$ are linearly dependent.